# which method to return directly an element of an class when i called this object?

Tags: python

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self, maxsize = 16):
        self.mylist = []

    def __call__(self):
        return self.mylist

    def append(self, element):
        if len(self.mylist) == self.maxsize :
            del self.mylist[0]
        self.mylist.append(element)
```

I have a list and I would like to call and have it return self.mylist directly to me

```
images = myclass()
for ind in range(5):
    images.append(ind)
```

when I call:

```
images()
```

I get : `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

that's good I want the same result without parenthesis:

```
images
```

I want get : `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

other example :

```
arr = np.array(images())
```

I want same result with follow syntax

```
arr = np.array(images)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `__str__` as well and use `join()` on the list

```
class myclass:
    def __str__(self):
        return f'[{", ".join(str(i) for i in self.mylist)}]'

images = myclass()
for ind in range(5):
    images.append(ind)

print(images) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```